# recieve or send data from html page to a php page, both stored at different location using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My code:

```
function send_data()
{
  var a=$("#username").val();
  var b=$("#password").val();
  $.post("http://localhost/login/login.php", {uname: a, pswd: b}, function(data)
  {
    $("#result").html(data);
  });
}
```

the above code is part of login.html page stored in MyDocuments section where as the data i wanna fetch from login.php stored under the www/htdocs folder of localhost .
its not working.

if i wrote only "login.php" instead of "http://localhost/login/login.php" and put the html file under the same folder, then it worked. But storing the html file in a different location, Jquery cant fetch / send  data to localhost. My Apache services are running well.

Comment: Try creating form with attribute `action="http://localhost/login/login.php" method="POST"`

Comment: what different location we are talking about? If you put html file elsewhere other than localhost then it wont work. You have to enable COR from javascript as well as php.

Answer (score 0):

if your html file is out side of wamp directory then php file inside it will not work . Please make sure both of your files are inside wamp.

Comment: well , got it later, it works !
pasting these at the top of the page helps perform a cross domain feature:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');